# Error "missing argument: -l (OptionParser::MissingArgument)" when bootstrapping EC2 instance with chef

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, bootstrapping

I'm very new to both Chef and AWS, but I'm trying to play around with both. I try to bootstrap an AWS instance with the following:

```
knife ec2 server create -I ami-62fd7152 -x ubuntu -f t1.micro --region 'us-west-2'
```

However, when I check my ec2 server list, the server is not listed, though it is listed in my node list. SSH'ing into my instance and checking my chef logs yields the following, but I'm not sure what to do with the information. What am I doing wrong?

```
~$ sudo chef-client -l
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mixlib-cli-1.3.0/lib/mixlib/cli.rb:226:in `parse_options': missing argument: -l (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application.rb:78:in `configure_chef'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application.rb:65:in `reconfigure'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application/client.rb:217:in `reconfigure'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/lib/chef/application.rb:71:in `run'
from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.0/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
from /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing jumping out at me is you need to specify the AWS key pair that you are using. AWS will prompt you to create one when you create a new server through the AWS console. When your ec2 instance comes up, Amazon places this key in the authorized_key file so that you can ssh into the instance. Knife needs to know what key to use, so that it can use the same key to ssh into the instance and bootstrap it. You can use passwords instead of key pairs, but I don't suggest it. It's generally considered bad practice for security reasons.

The option for ssh keys is '--ssh-key' or '-S'. You don't pass the path to where you have that key locally though. Instead just pass the name you've given it in the AWS console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added my key pair to my knife.rb file, which means it should be automatically passed to the create command right?

Comment: I haven't dug into the source too much, but if I'm reading [the source code on github](https://github.com/opscode/knife-ec2/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb#L91) correctly, it looks like you can specify it. Your file should look like `aws_ssh_key_id  'your_key_name'`. But remember the value isn't the path to where your key is stored locally. It needs to be just the name you gave it in the AWS console when you created it.

Comment: Hey Brandon, thanks for your help. Didn't resolve the issue but I did realize that it wasn't actually affecting my bootstrap. Everything is working as expected so it's become a moot point.